# What does Prolog assert/1 do with the term it is passed?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand what assert and retract do with the term they are passed.  If I run the following:

```
?- assertz(item(first)).
true.

?- assertz(item(second)).
true.

?- assertz((item(Y) :- =(Y, third), writeln(Y))).
true.

?- retract(item(X)).
X = first ;
X = second ;
false.
```

retract/1 removes all of the items but my writeln/1 is never called, so it appears retract is not actually *resolving* the term it is passed.  It looks like it is doing some special operation where it:

- Unifies the term with only facts (i.e. rules with no tail) in the database
- Retracts each one after applying the substitution from unification

Is this right? Or is something else happening here?

Said another way: If I write my own single argument rule, Prolog does not automatically unify item(X) with the database and iterate through all facts that are item/1. It just gives me item(X).  How is retract doing its magic?

```
?- assertz((myRule(X) :- writeln(X))).
true.

? myRule(item(X)).
item(_2556)
true.
```

**Answer with further clarification:**
Based on the answer by User9213, it appears that the answer is "retract (but not assert!) has a funny behavior where it does a simple unification of its term before it does something to the database".  I'm left wondering why other built-in functions that I've seen (like atom/1 and writeln/1) don't appear to do this. Maybe it is more common than I've experienced?

For consistency, it seems like retract should have required ground terms and if the user wanted to do something like my above example, they could have done this:

?- (item(X), retract(item(X))).

It all makes me think I'm missing something or maybe these built in functions were just inconsistently designed? Any clarification that would explain that would be great.

Comment: While `=(Y, third)` works, it's a lot less readable than it's equivalent `Y = third`, so I'd encourage you to ignore the "canonical" representation of such things and use the more clear one if possible. I think in this case you were trying to avoid some kind of body-inlining optimization, but I don't think there is anything like that; if anything, it probably works the other way around (try `asserta(foo), clause(foo, Body)` and you'll get `Body = true` back, implying it was equal to `foo :- true.`)

Comment: You mean `retract/1` not `revert/1`, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry!  Fixing...

Comment: Note that unless you call `item(third)`, you're never going to activate the body of the predicate you've added to the dynamic store. Remember that Prolog is not an expression-based language, it does not evaluate nested terms. If you want to call it and then retract it, you have to do `item(third), retract(item(third))` or `item(X), retract(item(X))` because the argument to `retract/1` is a _term_.

Comment: I was actually trying to test if the language was "resolving" the goal `item(X)` in the implementation of retract/1 when `retract(item(X))` was called.  If it was resolving it, then `item(X)` would unify with the rule `item(Y) :- ...`, Y would get assigned `item(third)` via the unification in the rule, and `writeln(Y)` would get called.  Just like if I ran the query `item(X)` after asserting the items in that example.  Or that was my intention at least.

Comment: If you did `retract(item(Y) :- Body)` then you'll get Y and Body unified, but like I said, that does not cause Prolog to _call_ Body. There's nothing special about the operators, including `:-`, `Head :- Body` may as well be `foo(Head, Body)` for as much as the dynamic store cares about it. Only by calling it does the body actually get evaluated, either in a query or via `call/N`.

Comment: Got it.  I was just trying to prove that the implementation of retract() did not do something I didn't understand or expect (like calling the body).  As you say, it doesn't.  Proven!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add my voice to the chorus, yes, all these predicates (`assert*`, `retract*`) manipulate the Prolog database of facts and rules; they **do not evaluate their arguments** as if they were facts or rules. Yes, they just do "syntactic" unification between their argument and the facts and rules in the database.

Prolog is a [homoiconic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity). The program can be manipulated as if it was data; the data structures can be interpreted as if they were the program. Most importantly: whether a certain structure is *data* or *program* depends only on the context.

You seem to understand this, but for the next poor soul that stumbles across your question and this answer, here is a toy example to demonstrate.

There is a [built-in predicate `atom/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom/1) that succeeds if its argument is, well, an atom:

```
?- atom(foo).
true.

?- atom(Bar). % Bar is a free variable, which is not an atom
false.

?- atom(atom(bar)). % atom(bar) is a compound term, which is not an atom
false.
```

But `atom(bar)` is just a compound term in the last query. It is a compound term with a functor atom/1. Its only argument is an atom. So if you now *queried* it:

```
?- atom(bar).
true.
```

There is also this really nice predicate [called `call`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metacall). It makes it even easier to blur the lines between program and data. The following three queries are identical in meaning:

```
?- atom(bar).
true.

?- call(atom, bar).
true.

?- call(atom(bar)).
true.
```

In addition, you can dynamically (at run-time) create a data structure and evaluate it as program. Here is a naive implementation of `call/2` that can evaluate predicates, provided a predicate name and a list of arguments. It [constructs the compound term using "univ"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) and evaluates it by just placing it in a slot where a subgoal is supposed to be. I'll call it `my_call/2` and I will add it to the database using `assertz`:

```
?- assertz((my_call(Name, Args) :- Goal =.. [Name|Args], Goal)).
true.

?- my_call(between, [1, 3, X]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

Do you see what is going on? (Note: it seems that `call` is a relatively new addition to Prolog. Before `call` was widely available, you had to do this trick if you wanted to meta-call predicates. I don't know this from experience, just educated guessing based on things I've read or heard and can't be bothered to cite right now.)

---

So, let's try that again. In reality things are more complicated, but very simplified:

A Prolog program is a set of predicates. Not ordered!

Each predicate is a list of clauses. It is a list because a predicate may have 0 or more clauses, and they have order.

A clause can be a fact or a rule.

A rule is a compound term with functor `:-/2`. Yes, this is right. To see what I mean:

```
?- assertz(:-(foo(X), between(1, 3, X))).
true.

?- listing(foo/1).
:- dynamic foo/1.

foo(A) :-
    between(1, 3, A).

true.
```

This is just another way to write it. It is more conventional.

So indeed, these two are very different:

```
foo(X). % a fact
foo(X) :- between(1, 3, X). % a rule
```

You cannot unify the one with the other. This is why, if you want to retract `foo(X) :- between(1, 3, X)`, you cannot just pass `foo(X)` as the argument to retract. Or, to complete your example:

```
?- assertz(item(first)).
true.

?- assertz(item(second)).
true.

?- assertz((item(Y) :- =(Y, third), writeln(Y))).
true.

?- retract(item(X)).
X = first ;
X = second ;
false.

?- retract((item(X) :- X = Y, writeln(X))).
Y = third.
```

Do you see it now?

Comment: Thanks. I do understand the fact that Prolog progams can be operated on like data and the notion of metaprogramming, etc. But you answered my base question: It seems retract (but not assert!) just has a funny behavior where it does a simple unification of its term before it changes the database. Other built-in functions that I've seen (like atom/1 above and writeln/1) don't appear to do this, maybe it is more common than I've experienced? I added more comments in the original question to clarify

Comment: @EricZinda I wll try to add a bit more detail at the bottom of this answer. I hope I am getting your question though....

Comment: @EricZinda But to be clear on that: no, I really don't see how `retract/1` does anything special at all. It unifies its argument with clauses in the database and retracts them.

Answer (score 2):

I had a vague memory of there being a `retractall/1` that lives alongside `retract/1` and it turns out the reason for it is situations like this. `retract/1` accepts a Prolog *term*, as the documentation states:

> **retract(+Term)**
>
> When Term is an atom or a term it is unified with the first unifying fact *or clause* in the database. The fact *or clause* is removed from the database.

Emphasis added by me.
This is illustrated by the following:

```
?- asserta(foo(X) :- X = 2 ; X = 4).
true.

?- foo(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 4.

?- retract(foo(X)).
false.

?- foo(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 4.

?- retract(foo(X) :- X = 2 ; X = 4).
true.

?- foo(X).
false.
```

Note that if you furnish the complete *clause* you gave to `asserta/1`, it will be retracted. As @CapelliC points out below, you can also furnish a clause with a variable as a parameter to retract things with bodies:

```
retract(foo(X) :- Y).
```

However, if you *do* want to retract things that match a pattern, you can use `retractall/1`, which the documentation states:

> **retractall(+Head)**
>
> All facts or clauses in the database for which the head unifies with Head are removed.

This is illustrated by the following:

```
?- asserta(foo(X) :- X = 2 ; X = 4).
true.

?- foo(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 4.

?- retractall(foo(X)).
true.

?- foo(X).
false.
```

Another important difference between these two is that `retract/1` will remove one thing at a time, and it will unify those things:

```
?- asserta(foo(X) :- X = 2).
true.

?- asserta(foo(X) :- X = 4).
true.

?- retract(foo(X) :- Y).
Y =  (X=4) ;
Y =  (X=2) .
```

This is in contrast to `retractall/1` which will remove *everything* that matches the pattern, without unifying anything:

```
?- asserta(foo(X) :- X=2).
true.

?- asserta(foo(X) :- X=4).
true.

?- foo(X).
X = 4 ;
X = 2.

?- retractall(foo(X)).
true.

?- foo(X).
false.
```

So, `retract/1` is really for doing one-at-a-time retractions but expects something shaped like the term you asserted, whereas `retractall/1` only wants a head, treats it as a pattern, and will remove as many things as match the pattern.

This certainly helped me improve my understanding of Prolog, so I hope it helps you as well!

Comment: good answer, but a bit misleading. No need retractall for **matching**: `?- retract(foo(X):-Y).
Y =  (X=2;X=4).`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not quite my question.  I was looking for a description of what assert/1 and retract/1 do with their single argument, since it is clearly being unified in some way (see my first code example) before trying to modify the database and not just taken "as is".  I'll add a bit more text to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @CapelliC I have updated the answer with your input.

Comment: @EricZinda they don't really _do_ anything with their arguments. `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` (`assert/1` is deprecated and I would encourage you to stop using it) don't do any special unifying at all, they just add their argument to the dynamic store. `retract/1` does unify its argument with something in the dynamic store as it removes it. What's confusing here is that asserting a full clause (i.e. a term with `:-`) seems to require you to retract it with a full clause as well (with `:-`), unless you use `retractall/1` which expects only a head.

Comment: Good point that only retract/1 does something specific with its arguments.  I thought the assert variants did too.  I'll update my answer and replace assert/1 with asserta/1

Answer (score 1):

The [definition of `assert` in swi-prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1) is:

> Assert a clause (fact or rule) into the database. The predicate asserta/1 asserts the clause as first clause of the predicate while assertz/1 assert the clause as last clause. **The deprecated assert/1 is equivalent to assertz/1**. If the program space for the target module is limited (see set_module/1), asserta/1 can raise a resource_error(program_space) exception. The example below adds two facts and a rule. Note the double parentheses around the rule.

Hence, it does not call or infer anything! It's just an assertion for the fact and the rule into the active memory.

Comment: In my example above, `retract(item(X))` actually retracts 2 items... so it is doing *something* more than than just reverting the term passed.  I.e. it is not actually retracting the term `item(X)`, it is doing something (that *something* is the point of my question) to it and retracting the terms `item(first)` and `item(second)`.  I'm pretty sure running `assert(item(X))` will do something analogous and not actually assert the fact `item(X)`

Comment: `retract(item(X))` is unifying `X=first` and retracting the first term from the dynamic store. If you ask for another solution, it will find the next fact and unify `X=second`. But because your third fact has a body, it doesn't seem to match `retract(item(X))` though it matches `retract(item(X) :- Y)` as @CapelliC points out.

Comment: Agreed. It seems like an odd thing to do given that other built-in functions I'm familiar with (which isn't many!) don't unify their arguments like that.  See my update to the question. I'm just trying to make sure there wasn't something else going on that I didn't understand.